# useState breaks a function component?

Tags: reactjs

I have to add some functionality to a small project and it's a pretty weird project I have to mention. As soon as I bring useState to any component, the component breaks. Even a simple one:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export function Example() { 
  const [count] = useState(0);
  return ( <div>{count}</div> );
}
```

gives an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
```

telling that some other component can't import and use Example component.

I can normally use other hooks (I actually use useEffect in some of components), but whenever I use useState I immediatelly get the error mentioned above. Since the project is very small, only a few components, there were no useStates before I started woking on it. Maybe there's somthing wrong with webpack config, I don't know.

Please help me fix this strange bug!

Comment: you wrote "exports" instead of "export"

Comment: if I just remove the line with useState and keep everything as it is, it's going to work fine. So I guess the problem is not the exports

Answer (score 0):

This is a fix for your code. Adding default to the export.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function Example() { 
  const [count] = useState(0);
  return ( <div>{count}</div> );
}
```

or

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() { 
  const [count] = useState(0);
  return ( <div>{count}</div> );
}

export default Example;
```

If you intend to export the component as such:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export function Example() { 
  const [count] = useState(0);
  return ( <div>{count}</div> );
}
```

you will have to import it this way:

```
import { Example } from "ACTUAL_PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try these three steps:

webpac.config.js file.

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Run that as Terminal.

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react babel-loader
```

And as .babelrc file.

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

Comment: found out that .jsx work fine with useState, while tsx (the extention used everywhere in the project) does not. Renamed components to someName.jsx and the problem is gone. Guess something is wrong with the typescript config